# Why does a list comprehension accept mixed `[Char]` and `[[Char]]` without error in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, polymorphism, list-comprehension, parametric-polymorphism

While learning Haskell I found something which puzzled me.

I don't understand why this code is valid:

```
Prelude> [y | y <- "a", y <- ["a"]]
["a"]
```

I tried to change to an explicit `[Char]` and got the same result (which makes sense):

```
Prelude> [y | y <- ['a'], y <- ["a"]]
["a"]
```

Surprisingly this is valid too :

```
Prelude> [y | y <- "a", y <- [["a"]]]
[["a"]]
```

[EDIT]
the error given is not related to the same fact :

<strike>This on the contrary is invalid as I would expect:</strike>

```
Prelude> [y | y <- 'a', y <- ['a']]
<interactive>:12:11: error:
* Couldn't match expected type `[t0]' with actual type `Char'
* In the expression: 'a'
  In a stmt of a list comprehension: y <- 'a'
  In the expression: [y | y <- 'a', y <- ['a']]
```

`[y | y <- 'a']` is invalid because 'a' is not a list.

[/EDIT]

I thought it was some usual mess caused by `String` vs `Char` but definitely not:

```
Prelude> [y | y <- [1], y <- [[2]]]
[[2]]
```

For the record I'm using GHCi version 8.2.2 and Arch Linux.

Comment: `y` seems to be 'overwritten' by the second part, since `[ y | y <- ["a"], y <- "a"]` evaluates to `"a"`. Also backed up by the fact that `[ y | y <- "a", y <- "b" ]`  being `"b"`.

Comment: @AJFarmar thanks for this addition. I am even more puzzled, I would guess the types would be invalid in this `[ y | y <- "a", y <- [[["b"]]], y <- "c"]`

Comment: Why would that be invalid, you have defined three `y`'s (this is *not* the same variable). And the yield is always in the lowest scope, so that takes values from the third `y`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turn on warnings! You should see that the first `y` is being shadowed by the second one.

It is somehow similar to

```
let y = True
in let y = "a"
in y
```

where the first definition is overshadowed, as if it were

```
let _ = True
in let y = "a"
in y
```

or even, removing the shadowed binding,

```
let y = "a"
in y
```

Similarly, a list comprehension such as

```
[y | y <- "a", y <- ["a"]]
```

evaluates to the same result as

```
[y | _ <- "a", y <- ["a"]]
-- or, if you prefer
[y | x <- "a", y <- ["a"]]
```

Note that, unlike the `let` above, in list comprehensions we can not simply remove the overshadowed binding `y <- ...`. For instance,

```
[y | y <- [1,2], y <- [3,4]]
```

produces `[3,4,3,4]`, unlike `[y | y <- [3,4]]`.

Here you can see the produced warning for each examples :

```
Prelude> :set -Wall

Prelude> [y | y <- "a", y <- ["a"]]

<interactive>:41:6: warning: [-Wunused-matches]
    Defined but not used: `y'

<interactive>:41:16: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for `y' shadows the existing binding
      bound at <interactive>:41:6
["a"]

Prelude> [y | x <- "a", y <- ["a"]]

<interactive>:47:6: warning: [-Wunused-matches]
    Defined but not used: `x'
["a"]

-- no warning here
Prelude> [y | _ <- "a", y <- ["a"]]
["a"]

Prelude> [y | y <- [1,2] , y <- [3,4]]

<interactive>:49:1: warning: [-Wtype-defaults]
    * Defaulting the following constraints to type `Integer'
        (Show a0) arising from a use of `print' at <interactive>:49:1-29
        (Num a0) arising from a use of `it' at <interactive>:49:1-29
    * In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it

<interactive>:49:6: warning: [-Wunused-matches]
    Defined but not used: `y'

<interactive>:49:12: warning: [-Wtype-defaults]
    * Defaulting the following constraint to type `Integer'
        Num t0 arising from the literal `1'
    * In the expression: 1
      In the expression: [1, 2]
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: y <- [1, 2]

<interactive>:49:12: warning: [-Wtype-defaults]
    * Defaulting the following constraint to type `Integer'
        Num t0 arising from the literal `1'
    * In the expression: 1
      In the expression: [1, 2]
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: y <- [1, 2]

<interactive>:49:19: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for `y' shadows the existing binding
      bound at <interactive>:49:6
[3,4,3,4]
```

Comment: thank you for this, meanwhile I does answer half of the question. The other half being why `[y | y <- 'a', y <- ['a']]` is giving an error and `[y | y <- ['a'], y <- [['a']]]` doesn't.

Comment: @Pierrot With `y <- 'a'`, you are attempting to draw an element from something that isn't a list.

Comment: More precisely, the list comprehension is equivalent to `"a" >>= (\y -> ["a"] >>= (\y -> return y))`, where you can clearly see the outer use of `y` being shadowed by the inner.